# get_result return object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Why get_result return object in this example?

```
function db_connect() {
    $db_host='localhost';
    $db_name='contact_manager';
    $db_user='root';
    $db_pass='';

    $connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    return $connection;
} 

$connection = db_connect();
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$query->execute();
$op = $query->get_result();
var_dump($op);
```

---

this is the vardump:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
["current_field"]=> int(0) 
["field_count"]=> int(4) 
["lengths"]=> NULL 
["num_rows"]=> int(24) 
["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)), `get_result()` returns a **resultset** for successful SELECT queries. Next you must extract data from the result set, using for example `$result->fetch_assoc()`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['user_id'];
}
```